# Get engine associated with SQLAlchemy Object

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have associated multiple engines with a SQLAlchemy Object. To use `sessionmaker` to create sessions I need to get the right `engine`. When I try db.engine (db is my SQLAlchemy object), I get the default engine. How do I get the other associated engines? I would prefer if I could give a key and get the right engine.

I used Flask's `SQLALCHEMY_BINDS` to associate more than one engine.

Answer (score 17):

Use `db.engines[bind_key]` to get a specific engine. `db.engine` is equivalent to `db.engines[None]`.

However, you should not need to set up sessions yourself, Flask-SQLAlchemy already has all the parts in place to use the correct bind when using `db.session`.

---

Prior to Flask-SQLAlchemy 3, use `db.get_engine(bind=bind_key)`. `db.get_engine()` is equivalent to `db.get_engine(bind=None)`.